# How do I get an index of elements being returned from loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to count the number of elements being returned in a for loop and if the index is equal or greater than 4 do something. What I'm trying to do is if there are more than 4 elements (by checking index) than I need to add an element and attached an event handler to it.

Here it is the code:

```
// getting element (ul) with index 4
var swatches = document.querySelectorAll(".colorSlivers")[4];   
// getting element's children
var shownThumb = document.querySelectorAll(".colorSlivers")[4].children;
// iterating on those elements 
for (var i = 0; i < shownThumb.length; i++) {                       
    if (shownThumb[i] >= 4) {
        console.log("greater or equal than four");
    } else {
       console.log("not greater or equal than four");
    }               
}
```

I'm learning Javascript now going through all sorts of courses online so forgive my elementary question. Thanks!

Comment: In your code "i" is the index number. why do you need another index no.

Comment: you can simply use - if (i >= 4) to compare the index

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: The code is returning four li's in my code so I want to say if it's greater than four li's than create a div. THe problem I'm having is that my if statement doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, except for why define `swatches` if you don't use it:

```
// getting element (ul) with index 4
var swatches = document.querySelectorAll(".colorSlivers")[4];   
// getting element's children
var shownThumb = swatches.children;
// iterating on those elements 
for (var i = 0; i < shownThumb.length; i++) {                       
    if (shownThumb[i] >= 4) {
        //code to add element and event goes here
    } else {
       //do nothing
    }               
}
```

If your `else` clause does nothing, you don't need it.

You haven't told us what element or what event, but the code looks something like:

```
newElement=document.createElement('myElement');
newElement.myEvent = eventHandler;
shownThumb[i].attach(newElement);

function eventHandler() {//code}
```

with `myElement` to be replaced with the name of your new element, e.g. `div`
and `myEvent` to be your event, e.g. `onclick`

Comment: I actually want to do two separate things in my if statement. If it's less than four being returned than do something, if it's greater than 4 than do something else.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I'm new to JS so it becomes hard to even ask questions. Not familiar with the correct terms. @jonmarkperry